# Is there a way to configure the ResourceHandler in jetty to serve a single file?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

In (embedded) jetty you can use ResourceHandler to serve files from your java user.dir. I want to cofigure a handler that allways serves a single file from this user.dir whenever its handle method is called, regardless of the request path. But I fail to configure my resource handler in such a way.

You can see what I tried below. The problem with this approach is that internally the ResourceHandler appends the request path to the base resource and tries to serve the file at that relative path. In other words, when I surf to "localhost:8080" it serves the correct file but when I surf to localhost:8080/randompath, it searches my local file system for the file at user.dir/hello.html/something, which is of course nonexistent and a 404 error is thrown.

Any ideas. At the moment I am considering writing my own handler but maybe you guys have more experience in configuring the ResourceHandler class. Kind regards and thanks in advance for your insights!

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;

public class SingleFileServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        resourceHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(new File("resources", "hello.html")));
        server.setHandler(resourceHandler);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'd probably try by subclassing `ResourceHandler` and overriding `getResource(String)`.